# How to trigger broadcast upload extension by iOS 11 Control Center?

Tags: ios, screensharing, replaykit

I have added a broadcast upload extension and my APP shows in the Control Center. But I am not able to fetch the video samples in the upload extension when I tapped the start live button. What's wrong? Anybody knows why? I would appreciate your reply.

Comment: Please post some source code so i can understand easily.

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure you add the extension to your containing app as `embedded binaries` check containing app build phase > Embedded App Extension is set to `Plugins`.In `info.plist` set `NSExtensionPrincipalClass` to `SampleHandler.m` is you didn't subclass the sample handler class. Also `RPBroadcastProcessMode` needs to be `RPBroadcastProcessModeSampleBuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

You need look next method if invoked:

`- (void)broadcastStartedWithSetupInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,NSObject *> *)setupInfo;
- (void)processSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer withType:(RPSampleBufferType)sampleBufferType ;`

at last, Find your plist file in broadcast extension target, and check NSExtension key for a dictionary, Find NSExtensionPrincipalClass's value is equol to your RPBroadcastSampleHandler subclass